# WebSphere Commerce JAX-WS AxisFault

Tags: security, jax-ws, axis, websphere-commerce

I am getting this exception in WebSphere Commerce. No idea why. This may or may not be related to Commerce. I could not find much info on the internet for this exception. Any insight/help would be much appreciated.

```
[8/31/11 9:40:39:545 EDT] 00000025 CommerceSrvr  E com.ibm.commerce.command.ECCommandTarget executeCommand CMN0420E: The following command exception has occurred during processing: "

javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Out request Policy Set for SSL is set to true for protocol: http

javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Out request Policy Set for SSL is set to true for protocol: http
      at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.createWebServiceException(ExceptionFactory.java:175)
      at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.makeWebServiceException(ExceptionFactory.java:70)
      at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.makeWebServiceException(ExceptionFactory.java:128)
      at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.core.controller.impl.AxisInvocationController.execute(AxisInvocationController.java:572)

...

Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Out request Policy Set for SSL is set to true for protocol: http
      at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.http.SOAPOverHTTPSender.setupTransportClientProperties(SOAPOverHTTPSender.java:1916)
      at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.http.SOAPOverHTTPSender.<init>(SOAPOverHTTPSender.java:404)
      at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.http.HTTPTransportSender.invoke(HTTPTransportSender.java:350)
      at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:531)
      at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:401)
      at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:228)
      at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:163)
      at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.core.controller.impl.AxisInvocationController.execute(AxisInvocationController.java:567)
```

Answer (score 0):

We have a set of JAX-WS services. One of them needs WS-Security enabled. Others are just plain HTTP calls.

WS-Security was enabled using  policy sets and client bindings on RAD. This was applied to  in the environment configuration. Hence the exception.

Solution: Detach the policy set and client bindings from  and attach it to the specific service that needs it.

Comment: In the future, a ticket to IBM Software Support would have told you the answer.   You get support as part of your software purchase.

Comment: from where i can detach the policy?